# How do can I use SUMPRODUCT and MAX function for Summing Data on Multiple Sheets?

Tags: excel, max, criteria, countif, sumproduct

In simple terms, I have sheet 1 and Sheet 2.

In Cell F3 on Sheet 1, I need to get the sum of all max order values in sheet 2 corresponding to week and name criteria in columns A & B in sheet 1.

Currently using this formula =SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(--(COUNTIF(A3:A9,Sheet2!A:A) * COUNTIF(B3:B9,Sheet2!B:B)>0),0),Sheet2!C:C)

The  formula above seemed to be okay but it only adds all values in sheet 2 instead of only the maximum to give 16300.
If it works as I want, it should add only 7000 for john max from wk2 (not 5000 or both) + 3000 (paul wk 2) + 200 (peter wk 1) = 10200

I wonder if Tweaking with a max function somehow will make a difference?

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmG0I.png)

[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRC5E.png)

Comment: Consider using a pivot table, set the row values to names, and the value field to orders, right click orders and change from sum/count to MAX function.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Perhaps this will work, but I need a formula which goes into a macro. Moreso, using a pivot makes it less automated for the purpose I'm seeking. In current use, a macro plugs the current formula into a cell after another code has populated all the name/week data, and then the sum of all order values is calculated. I'm only just trying to get the formula to pick only max values now.

Comment: First off i would recommend that you do not inject cell formulas using macros/VBA, it seems counter intuitive. You can easily make pivot's automated (what troubles are you having doing this?) , and i would suggest that you scrap sheet 1 and replace with a pivot using sheet 2 as source, it is very easy and can do everything you ask in your question, even the max grouping by weeks+name matches.  If you really want to go ahead and make you life harder: https://www.exceltip.com/excel-array-formulas/find-the-maximum-numerical-value-in-a-list-based-on-a-criteria-in-microsoft-excel.html